# Express Amount In Words with Decimal Value

Tags: php, class

Im using the number formatter class in php and it needs to format it in currency and also in words, the problem is the value that it needs to be formatted has decimal value and it gives me the value two thousand nine hundred three point zero four and it shoud be two thousand nine hundred three and four cents, if the value has decimal it gives me a literal word point here is my code

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$formated = $f->format(2903.04);
```

please help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no defined spell-out formatter for currency, and while [you could probably write one](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classRuleBasedNumberFormat.html#details) I think that that might be a bit of overkill.

What you could do instead is split the dollars as cents into separate values, spell those out, and combine them.

First and foremost though, you do ***not*** want to store or compute currencies with floating point representations. I was going to save this point for last, but I couldn't even get through the initial steps before floating point errors crept in.

```
$v = 2903.04;
$d = (int)$v; // casting to int discards decimal portion
$c = (int)(($v - $d) * 100);

var_dump($v, $d, ($v - $d) * 100, $c);
```

Output:

```
float(2903.04)
int(2903)
float(3.9999999999964)
int(3)
```

Use something like [moneyphp/money](https://packagist.org/packages/moneyphp/money) which stores monetary values as integer amounts of base currency units. [eg: $2903.04 == 290304] This avoids errors like the above, as well as messy kludges to do with rounding. Additionally, money libraries will implement *safe* mathematical operations to do operations like dividing $1.00 among 3 recipients without splitting or losing pennies.

Instead, let's write the code like:

```
$a = 290304;            // full amount in cents
$c = $a % 100;          // cent remainder
$d = ($a - $c) / 100;   // dollars

$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);

var_dump(
    $a, $d, $c,
    sprintf("%s dollars and %s cents", $f->format($d), $f->format($c))
);
```

Output:

```
int(290304)
int(2903)
int(4)
string(54) "two thousand nine hundred three dollars and four cents"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my working converter : https://smctgroup.com/contracts/number.php

Input:  **2903.04** 
Output : **Two Thousand Nine Hundred Three Pesos and Four Centavos**
You can change Pesos to Dollar

 You can use this function:

```
function makewords($numval)
{


$moneystr = "";
$num_arr = explode(".", $numval);
$decnum = $num_arr[1];

// handle the millions
$milval = (integer)($numval / 1000000);
if($milval > 0)
  {
  $moneystr = getwords($milval) . " Million";
  }

// handle the thousands
$workval = $numval - ($milval * 1000000); // get rid of millions
$thouval = (integer)($workval / 1000);
if($thouval > 0)
  {
  $workword = getwords($thouval);
  if ($moneystr == "")
    {
    $moneystr = $workword . " Thousand";
    }     
  else
    {
    $moneystr .= " " . $workword . " Thousand";
    }
  }

// handle all the rest of the dollars
$workval = $workval - ($thouval * 1000); // get rid of thousands
$tensval = (integer)($workval);
if ($moneystr == "")
  {
  if ($tensval > 0)
    {
    $moneystr = getwords($tensval);
    }
  else
    {
    $moneystr = "Zero";
    }
  }
else // non zero values in hundreds and up
  {
  $workword = getwords($tensval);
  $moneystr .= " " . $workword;
  }

// plural or singular 'dollar'
$workval = (integer)($numval);
if ($workval == 1)
  {
  $moneystr .= " Peso";
  }
else
  {
  $moneystr .= " Pesos";
  }


// //My cents

// if ($workint > 0) {
//     $moneystr .= " and ";
//     if ($workint < 20) {
//       $moneystr .= $ones[$workint];
//     } elseif ($workint < 100) {
//       $moneystr .= $tens[substr($workint, 0, 1)];
//       $moneystr .= " ".$ones[substr($workint, 1, 1)];
//     }
//   }



// do the pennies - use printf so that we get the
// same rounding as printf
$workstr = sprintf("&#37;3.2f",$numval); // convert to a string
$intstr = substr($workstr,strlen - 2, 2);
$workint = (integer)($intstr);


if($decnum>0) {

  $moneystr .= " and ";
  if ($workint == 0)
    {
    $moneystr .= "Zero";
    }
  else
    {
    $moneystr .= getwords($decnum);
    }
  if ($workint == 1)
    {
    $moneystr .= " Centavo";
    }
  else
    {
    $moneystr .= " Centavos";
    }
}
// done - let's get out of here!
return $moneystr;
}
```